# Control duration of the session PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am very beginner in web development. I spent some time realizing the way to limit session time in PHP. I have read Stackoverflow suggestions but none of them seems to work for me (cookies-might be edited by user, AJAX communication-extra load on server and static PHP - what about passive tabs in browser? Validation using session vars).

I have in mind this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = 'logout.php';
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

...to limit session time for users. This system will be used in a management web app. Could anyone point out potential drawbacks of my approach, because it seems to be too simple to be good?

Comment: Disabling Javascript is easy to do and would prevent this from running.

Comment: The problem with this script is the browser will go to "logout.php" in 10 seconds  everytime this script is loaded. And also the 10 sec countdown will restart when you refresh this page.

Comment: Thanks, so far it seems fine for my purpose. My system will force users to enable javascript due to dynamic interaction with user and database.  And when user inactive for 10 sec(will be increased) it will log him out.

Comment: So if you open another tab after 5min without closing the other one, it would log you out after 5min instead of 10?

Comment: @Capsule you are right, I would escape this behavior though. Will window.onblur location.reload help me out with this?

Comment: I think it would but switching from the browser to another application would also trigger that and artificially extend the session even if the user doesn't interact with the website when switching back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 function check_user_is_valid () {
    //Start our session.
    session_start();

    //Expire the session if user is inactive for 30
    //minutes or more.
    $expireAfter = 30;

    //Check to see if our "last action" session
    //variable has been set.
    if(isset($_SESSION['last_action'])){

        //Figure out how many seconds have passed
        //since the user was last active.
        $secondsInactive = time()-$_SESSION['last_action'];

        //Convert our minutes into seconds.
        $expireAfterSeconds = $expireAfter * 60;

        //Check to see if they have been inactive for too long.
        if($secondsInactive >= $expireAfterSeconds){
            //User has been inactive for too long.
            //Kill their session.
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
} 

//Assign the current timestamp as the user's
//latest activity
$_SESSION['last_action'] = time();
```

Call check_user_is_valid () function on every php page to check if the user have valid session.It will automatically destroy session if page is still for 30 minutes.

Update the value of $_SESSION['last_login'] variable with new time on every page, so that the user get 30 minutes session for each and every page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think your approach wouldn't work for passive tabs in browser. Some action should trigger this script.

Comment: Why don't you try with an ajax method. You can put this script in ajax call and can check the session value on every passive tab click